# Battery over-discharge protection

Tags: batteries, protection, low-voltage, over-discharge

I am studying NiMH battery charging and using such a battery on a board to feed other circuits. I would like to add a protection circuit that provides protection for over-discharging the battery at low voltage. Could you give me an idea how can I built this type of circuit?

Comment: How many cells in series?

Comment: 7 cells in series (9v battery package)

Answer (score 0):

When I need to design a circuit, I do an image search for the name of the circuit. Like this: [low voltage cutoff circuit](https://www.google.com/search?q=low+voltage+cutoff+circuit&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwioia394Mn7AhUvHTQIHWXWDQYQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1746&bih=861&dpr=1).